# PHP if else always goes to else condition

Tags: php

I have below script to grab $_REQUEST data to perform DB process, I can perform this script without any issue by assigning TEST DATA for the test at same server, BUT in real time testing, it always show `Transaction aborted! Specific transaction not found!` message even `$trx !== FALSE` is perform, I can check all data are updated in DB as well, it stop here and the rest of process such as `points deduction` and `create invoice` are not perform, I wonder why `TEST DATA` and `REAL TIME DATA` are in different behavior and result, both tested at same server environment, all setting are same, REAL TIME DATA also correct for the test.

I need someone help looks at my code is it anything goes wrong??

```
<?php

//Real time data get from payment provider
$refNo        = $_REQUEST['RefNo'];
$transId      = $_REQUEST['TransId'];
$authcode     = $_REQUEST['AuthCode'];
$eStatus      = $_REQUEST['Status'];
$signature    = $_REQUEST['Signature'];


/* TEST DATA */
$eStatus     = 1;
$refNo       = '1468408036-0JSKZ8';
$transId     = 'T108902465200';
$authcode    = '3FL931320S778334X';
$signature   = 'zVq0m7WKxyDuOKVdExIQbaoJCi0=';


if($eStatus == 1){

        try {

            // Check whether have such order in db
            // If yes, get all relevant details for invoice generation.
            $trx = $buyer->get_transaction_if_exist(filter_var($refNo, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING), $mysqli);

            if($trx !== FALSE){

                //Update payment status in db
                $postVars = array(
                                'payment_status' => 'completed',
                                'payment_id' => $transId,
                                'auth_code' => $authcode,
                                'signature' => $signature
                            );

                if($buyer->update($postVars, 'pp_transaction', 'order_num', $refNo, $mysqli) === TRUE){

                    //perform Points deduction if found checkout with Points+Cash
                    $points_consume  = $trx->total_points_consume;
                    $checkout_method = $trx->checkout_method;
                    $member_id = $trx->member_id;

                    //get existing Points
                    $cust = $buyer->get_customer_by_id($account_id, $mysqli);
                    $leftover_Points = $cust->my_points - $points_consume;

                    if($checkout_method == 2){

                        //update deduction points to member account 
                        $arr1 = array('my_points' => $leftover_Points);
                        $buyer->update($arr1, 'members', 'acct_id', $member_id, $mysqli);

                        //log
                        $logVar = array(
                                    'acct_id' => $account_id,
                                    'order_num' => $refNo,
                                    'point_consume' => $points_consume
                                );
                        $buyer->insert($logVar, 'points_consume_log', $mysqli);
                    }


                    //Generate invoice and send to buyer
                    require(WEBROOT.'/createInvoice.php');
                    require(WEBROOT.'/sendInvoice.php');


                }

            }else{

                //Cannot found specific transaction record in DB
                $payment_error = 'Transaction aborted!';
                $error_desc = 'Specific transaction not found!';

            }

        } catch (Exception $e) {

            $payment_error = $e->getMessage();
            //die();
        }

}

?>
```

Query to check if such order are exist:

```
public function get_transaction_if_exist($refno, $mysqli)
{
    if(empty($refno)){
        return false;
    }

    $q  = "SELECT * FROM `pp_transaction` ";
    $q .= "WHERE order_num='".$refno."' ";
    $q .= "AND payment_status IN('pending','failed')";

    $sql = $mysqli->query($q);

    if($sql->num_rows > 0){
        $obj = $sql->fetch_object();
        return $obj;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Big Thanks.

Comment: what is $buyer? Where did you initialize that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the possibilities I can think of as to why it works with test data but not real data:

1. The real data's `$refno` is not found, or the matching record's `payment_status` is not `IN ('pending','failed')`
2. If the transaction exists, maybe the http request is not well formed, such that the `$refNo` value passed to the script is not what you expect
3. If the transaction exists, and the `$refNo` is correct, maybe there is an error executing the query, so it never successfully runs the `SELECT` command

**To test scenario 1**

Use all real data as before, but hardcode `$refNo` with a number that you know is in the database, on a record whose `payment_status` you know is either `pending` or `failed`.  If the script works, you've found your problem.

**To test scenario 2**

Add `var_dump($refno); die();` within the `get_transaction_if_exist` function before you run the query. Verify that the value echoed is a good number in line with scenario 1.

**To test scenario 3**

Add some error handling to `get_transaction_if_exist`

```
$sql = $mysqli->query($q);
if($sql === false){
    //there was an error
    die('SQL error: '$mysqli->error);
}
```

If an SQL error is printed, you've found your problem

Comment: FYI, I can run this query `$buyer->update($postVars, 'pp_transaction', 'order_num', $refNo, $mysqli)===TRUE` without problem, I can seen all data are stored in DB

Comment: Thanks. That info doesn't change my answer or my recommendations because your script never gets to the `->update` line when it fails as you described.

Comment: the **test scenario 1** has find the issue, I did hardcode **$refNo** and the rest of data resume as real-time data, the whole process is completely done. But I wonder why **$refNo = $_REQUEST['RefNo'];** is failed as argument for method **get_transaction_if_exist()**? Can you give me an idea? Thanks!

Comment: My guess is that `RefNo` is not the correct name. maybe `refNo` or `refno` is  what you need.  I would outpu all the parameters on screen with `print_r($_REQUEST)` and look closely for that value. This is the 2nd possibility I highlighted in my answer